# How to detect user has scrolled to bottom of web page on their iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, dom-events

I want a function that can be called when user has scrolled to bottom of a web page on their iPhone. (For example, to load in more data.) Kind of like Facebook does when you scroll to the bottom of your Wall or News Feed.

I have tried the **jQuery.scroll** handler, but when I test it on an iPhone it doesn't work. Any answer that works will do. I don't need to use jQuery if not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `window.onscroll` event:

`window.onscroll = function(ev) { alert(ev.offsetY); };`

You'll need to check the scroll position against `scrollHeight` to see if you are at the bottom.